# How to change a worksheet Macro to run a double click sub procedure over a whole workbook in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that when I double click a cell it inserts a checkmark.  I use it very often and would like to have it load and run with every sheet, but I do not know what to change to have it in my Personal.XLSB Alternatively, I'd like to code it so it works on all sheets in a Workbook.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:Z500")) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
    Target.ClearContents
    Cancel = True
Else
    Target.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
    Cancel = True
End If
End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Many thanks if anyone could help me with this, I've tried a few things, but it does not work.

Comment: read about Excel add-ins

Comment: Have a look at this, https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/personal.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say for now you want to apply this code to all of the worksheet so you don't need to create this code one by one for all of the sheets. Simply, in the VBE, double click `ThisWorkbook` (left explorer) and on the right window on top choose `Workbook` for the left drop down and on the right drop down you will have access to all of the events that you can have for worksheets, the difference is that they start with `sheet` instead of `worksheet` so for this one you should choose `SheetBeforeDoubleClick`. Paste the content of your code there and that code will work on all of your worksheets, even the one you create after pasting this code.